# Visiting Philipines in 12 hours layover

Tags: layovers, spanish-citizens, manila

I am arriving to Manila tomorrow, I am there just to connect flights from London to Saigon. Since I have 12 hours I would like to spent a few exploring the city. Could I face any problem from doing that, related to visa (spanish citizen) or is there something that I should be concerned?

Thank you for taking your time, I am looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't need a visa.  You can check here: [Applying for a Philippine Visa](https://www.philippine-embassy.org.sg/consular/visa/important-visa-information/)
.

However, be careful with the timing.  Manila traffic is terrible and it could take a long time to get to the city centre and back.  Airport procedures can be slow.  You will be able to make a token visit, enough to say: "I've been to Manila" but not much more than that.

If you want to do something specific, e.g. visit the palace, then research it carefully to ensure that it is feasible.

Comment: Tell us the day and time that you expect to arrive.  I hope that it is not during working hours.